# Is $AB=\{ab:a\in A, b\in B\}$ open.

Tags: real-analysis

Is the set $AB=\{ab:a\in A, b\in B\}$ open in $\mathbb{R}$ where $A$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$($B$ is any set of reals)? What if $B$ is also open? For me its seems that $AB$ is open if any one of $A$ or $B$ is open . But don't know exactly how. Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about $B=\{0\}$?

Comment: ohhoo then it becomes non open....what if $B$ is also open...

Comment: I think it would be true if $A$ is open and $B$ contains at least one point other than $0$ but doesn't contains $0$ (or the other way round), because then you can write $AB$ as $$AB=\cup_{b\in B, b\ne 0} bA.$$ which is union of open sets.

Comment: Here's an interesting observation to make: the map $f(a,b) = (ab,a/b)$ is continuous with continuous inverse over $\Bbb R_+^2$

Comment: @neelkanth Did you solve your question when $B$ contains $0$? 'Cause the accepted answer does not seem to deal with this case...

Comment: i accept the question as it gives me way to check....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view $AB$ as simply being

$$\bigcup_{b\in B}bA.$$

Think about what happens in your cases ($0\in B$ (e.g. $B = \{0\}$), etc.).

Comment: Its means that if $B$ is open then $AB$ is also open??

Comment: As arbitrary union of open set is open...

Comment: Yep that is correct!